# using AlarmManager to schedule a notification to another app using WakefulBroadcastReceiver and IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

I have the ability to build a notification that opens this app I'm working on (see: `setupNotification` method in my `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`). Now, I'm trying to use the same functionality to create a notification that will open another app(see: `scheduleNotification` method in my `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`). The onReceive method of my `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` will not fire when I try it this second way. The intent has to be the issue, but I don't see why. Here's the classes in question:

```
public class NotificationEventReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
private static final String ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE = "ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE";
private static final String ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION = "ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION";
private static final int NOTIFICATIONS_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS = 1;

public static void setupNotification(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context, null);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            getTriggerAt(new Date()),
            alarmIntent);
}

public static void scheduleNotification(Context context, Date dateTime, AppInfo app) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent i = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.getPackageName());
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context, i);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getTriggerAt(new Date()), alarmIntent);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("onReceive Intent", intent.toString());

    String action = intent.getAction();
    Intent serviceIntent = null;
    if (ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE.equals(action)) {
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive from alarm, starting notification service");
        serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentStartNotificationService(context);
    } else if (ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION.equals(action)) {
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive delete notification action, starting notification service to handle delete");
        serviceIntent = NotificationIntentService.createIntentDeleteNotification(context);
    }

    if (serviceIntent != null) {
        startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
    }
}

private static long getTriggerAt(Date now) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(now);
    //calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, NOTIFICATIONS_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS);
    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

private static PendingIntent getStartPendingIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (null == intent){
        intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
    }
    intent.setAction(ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Log.d("settingPendIntent", intent.toString());
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static PendingIntent getDeleteIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
}
```

and the service to build the notification. I also need a way to make the notification intent to be the intent I'm building in `scheduleNotification()`, but I don't even get that far, because onReceive is not firing for the above class...anyway

```
public class NotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private static final String ACTION_START = "ACTION_START";
private static final String ACTION_DELETE = "ACTION_DELETE";
//    private static Intent permIntent;

public NotificationIntentService() {
    super(NotificationIntentService.class.getSimpleName());
}

public static Intent createIntentStartNotificationService(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_START);
//        permIntent = intent;
    return intent;
}

public static Intent createIntentDeleteNotification(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onHandleIntent, started handling a notification event");
    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_START.equals(action)) {
            processStartNotification(intent);
        }
        if (ACTION_DELETE.equals(action)) {
            processDeleteNotification(intent);
        }
    } finally {
        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}

private void processDeleteNotification(Intent intent) {
    // Log something?
}

private void processStartNotification(Intent intent) {
    // Do something. For example, fetch fresh data from backend to create a rich notification?

    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .setContentText("This notification has been triggered by Notification Service")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_noti)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_noti));
    // TODO: small icon will be app default, use setLargeIcon to show the app's icon

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
//                permIntent,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setDeleteIntent(NotificationEventReceiver.getDeleteIntent(this));

    final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since u haven't posted ur Androidmanifest.xml code, i assume i have right to ask you that " Have u registered receiver and services" in manifest..??

Comment: I have. As I said, it's working to generate a notification with an intent that launches the same app, but not for an intent to launch another app.